# Do not fill DropDownList if upstanding UserControl isn't visible

Tags: .net, asp.net, data-binding, sqldatasource

I have page Add.aspx containing a number of `UserControls`: AddRequest.ascx, AddOperation.ascx, AddObject.ascx, etc. Depending on `Request["type"]` one control becomes visible.

Each `UserControl` contains a number of `DropDownList`s that are being filled via `SqlDataSource` from DB. For example, types, statuses, currencies, etc.

It seems that appropriate `SqlDataSource`s queries DB even if it's `UserControl`-owner isn't visible. So having `n` controls, only `1` query is really needed and `n-1` are not.

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should only load the user control you are going to display.
Something like:

```
Control myControl = LoadControl("SomeControl.ascx");
```

You can then add the control to a placeholder.
This way you avoid loading unnecessary controls to your page and their round trips to the database are also not executed.

Answer (score 2):

Try making the loading of the usercontrols imperative in nature (as demonstrated by @Dante) instead of declarative (by registering it in the ASPX, for instance). That way, only that control which is explicitly loaded should invoke it's respective Datasource controls).